# Slim can't find a callable to respond to a request

Tags: controller, slim

I have created a Slim 4 app and followed the official guide.

Under `public/`, I created an `index.php`:

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

use \Controllers\HomeController;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();
//$app->addRoutingMiddleware();
$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
    return $response;
});

$app->get('/home', HomeController::class.':home');

$app->run();
```

The call to `/` works fine.

Now I created a `HomeController.php` under `src/Controllers`:

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;

use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

class HomeController
{
    private $container;
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    public function home(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $response->getBody()->write("Hello World");
        return $response;
    }
}
```

But when I try `/home`, it prompts an error: `Message: Callable Controllers\HomeController::home() does not exist`.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Based on @odan input, I have updated my `composer.json` file and it moves on but now I have another issue. With these few lines in my `HomeController.php`:

```
private $container;
    public  function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
```

The error now is:  `App\Controllers\HomeController::__construct(): Argument #1 ($container) must be of type Psr\Container\ContainerInterface, null given, called in /vagrant/api.slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php on line`

I can comment out these few lines and the call works. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: I assume that the composer.json is missing the "autoload" section for the "\Controllers" namespace. Have you checked this?

Comment: Note: The DI Container should only be used within the "infratructure", but not in the application itself. I would recommend to use Single Action Controllers instead. See [here](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html)

Comment: @odan Thanks. I know this approach but wants to avoid this as much as I can.